# Exporting to Template Creating New Tab

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access database (access 2016) and have created a function to export a query into a template in excel, specifically to a tab called "Roster". When the function runs it does export the query to the template as expected, however it creates a new tab called "Roster1" instead of placing it in the existing tab.

I have searched around and seen suggestions about adding a $ or ! to either the beginning or end of the sheet name, however this only gives me an error message:

> Run-time error '3125':
>
> '$Roster' is not a valid name. Make sure it does not include
>   characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

The code I am using is as follows:

```vb
Function Transfer()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False 'prevents you from getting pop up messages

    Dim xlsxDestinationWorkbook As String

    FileCopy "\\cnwshare\shared13\0175\Brian_Alterman\Reporting\File_Staging\Weekly_Vets\Weekly_Vet_Roster_Template.xlsx", _
             "\\cnwshare\shared13\0175\Brian_Alterman\Reporting\File_Staging\Weekly_Vets\Weekly_Vet_Roster_" & _
                Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".xlsx"

    xlsxDestinationWorkbook = "\\cnwshare\shared13\0175\Brian_Alterman\Reporting\File_Staging\Weekly_Vets\Weekly_Vet_Roster_" & _
                                Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".xlsx"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "SEL_Final_Data", xlsxDestinationWorkbook, False, "Roster"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Counts_Tab", xlsxDestinationWorkbook, False, "Counts"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True ' ends the "no pop up messages function"
End Function
```

I had previously used this at my last job but we were on a different version of office (can't recall which, but it was older).

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I worked in this space.  That said you might want to consider using the "copy" command instead of what you have set up here.  It's more efficient IIRC, and will not create a new tab like you are experiencing.

```
Set rstName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("[Table/Query]")
    rstName.MoveLast
    rstName.MoveFirst 'Rewind to the first record
    objMyWorkbook.Sheets(strSheet).Range("A2:W2").CopyFromRecordset rstName
    rstName.Close
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it